# Adding data into List VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to add some data into 'List' form(exactly copy).
Below is my code.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub addToListSample_Click()
Dim introw As Integer

introw = ListSample.ListIndex + 1

ListSample.Column(0, introw) = TextP11.Value
ListSample.Column(1, introw) = TextP12.Value
ListSample.Column(2, introw) = TextP13.Value
ListSample.Column(3, introw) = TextP14.Value
ListSample.Column(4, introw) = TextP15.Value
ListSample.Column(5, introw) = TextP16.Value
ListSample.Column(6, introw) = TextP17.Value
End Sub
```

But when I execute it, I get following error.
"Run-time error '424' : Object required"

Why do I get this error? I think this is pretty easy code, but I don't know why this error keep annoying me....

Comment: the object name is wrong. is it in a module or directly in the form?

Comment: I have made a List form and when I click it, above code will be executed. It is not in module. It is in 'Microsft Access Class Obejcts'.

Comment: Is this a List Box?

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing

```
introw = ListSample.ListIndex + 1
```

to

```
introw = Me.ListSample.ListIndex + 1
```

At some point you will probably also have to check that the listbox is actually selected or you will always get 0.

edit:

```
'add a row with hard-coded values:
'Dim introw As Integer
'introw = Me.lstEmpty.ListIndex + 1 '<-- not really needed when using AddItem.
'Me.lstEmpty.AddItem "value 1;value 2"

'or add a row using values from textboxes:
Me.ListSample.AddItem TextP11.Value & ";" & TextP12.Value & ";" & TextP13.Value
```

This will add values to one row, in different columns.
Your list box's **Row Source Type** will have to be set to **Value List**.
The **Column Count** will have to match the number of columns you're adding.